# Existentialism and bad faith

Tags: philosophy-of-language, existentialism

Where do the values that existentialists formulate come from? If accepting a path laid out by someone else is considered "bad faith", then can we accept values shared with anyone other than ourselves? For example, if an existentialist decides that he values fidelity and truthfulness, doesn't he have to accept all of the connotations and meanings of truthfulness that society and language have made "truthfulness" to mean, including sources like religion and government? Can a value truly be separated from the context that it exists in? Since nothing really exists independently from anything else, is it possible to live authentically without bad faith?
I feel like I'm probably not asking this question in the best way possible, but I'm having trouble formulating it in a way that makes the most sense. Sorry if it's not entirely clear.

Comment: See [Sartre : Autenticity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/authenticity/#SarDeBea) : "human beings are not merely characterized by facticity and transcendence; they are also seen as embodying a deep and irreconcilable tension between facticity and transcendence. This tension comes to the fore in Sartre's account of “bad faith”. Bad faith, a kind of self-deception, involves believing or taking oneself to be an X while all along one is (and knows oneself to be) actually a Y.  1/2

Comment: The most familiar form of bad faith is acting as if one were a mere thing—solely facticity—and thereby denying one's own freedom to make oneself into something very different. Thus, the person who thinks she is a coward “just as a matter of fact” is excluding from view the ability to transform her existence through changed ways of behaving. Such bad faith is a denial of transcendence or freedom." 2/2

Comment: Typical existentialists do not formulate values to live according to, they say your actual deeds testify on your values. And values are not permanent. To "find oneself", to try to stick to some system of values, either personal or conventional, is one of many facets of _bad faith_, by the way.